# call specific elements in a list with for-each loop, function definition and if-else-elif statements

Tags: python, list, function, loops, if-statement

Sorry if the title is not worded properly. First year student currently doing a unit that focuses on the concepts of Python.

How can I call specific elements (if thats the term for it) within a list with a function definition, for_each loop, function definition and if-else-elif statements.

Say this is my list:

```
data_sets = [
    ['0', ['1', '2', '3']],
    ['4', ['5', '6', '7']]]
```

And say this is my function definition:

```
def example(dataset):
    for element in dataset:
        if '1' in dataset:
            return 'Yeah!'
        else:
            return 'Nope!'
```

I do not understand why it does not return 'Yeah!' when I type data_sets[0]. I know that data_sets[0][1] does return 'Yeah!' but i want to use only one square bracket ([0]) and not two ([0][1]) to return a 'Yeah!'

```
example(data_sets[0])
#'Nope!'
```

I am meant to do an exercise that uses different numbers, etc., and it says I should be able to do that with one square bracket ([0]), but I dont know how. We aren't told what to do for the function definition, for each loop, and if-else statements, but we are given the list, and we are expected to do a similar thing with one square bracket. So that may mean I might be doing the function definition, for each loop and if-else statements wrong.

Apologies if I have used incorrect terms or jargon as I am only a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

List `['0', ['1', '2', '3']]` consists of *two* elements: `'0'` and `['1', '2', '3']`. Neither of them is `'1'`. So, `'1'` is not in `data_sets[0]`. However, `['1', '2', '3']` has three elements, and one of them is `'1'`. So, `'1'` is in `data_sets[0][1]`. You can first flatten the list (as explained in [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)) and then check if `'1'` is in the flattened list.

Answer (score 0):

`['0', ['1', '2', '3']]` has a string and a list. You wanted to check if the string `'1'` was in the list, however, the only string in the list is `'0'`. This is why it returns `nope`. Neither of the elements are `'1'`

Answer (score 0):

try this , first you need to flatten your list with list comprehension and then check

```
def example(dataset):
    dataset = [item for sublist in dataset for item in sublist]
    for element in dataset:
        if '1' in dataset:
            return 'Yeah!'
        else:
            return 'Nope!'
```

and now when you try you code : here is the output :

```
In [18]: example(dataset[0])
Out[18]: 'Yeah!'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to check if any element in the dataset contains `1`:

```
def example(dataset):
    for element in dataset:
        if any('1' in x for x in dataset):
            return 'Yeah!'
        else:
            return 'Nope!'

data_sets = [
    ['0', ['1', '2', '3']],
    ['4', ['5', '6', '7']]]

print(example(data_sets[0]))
# Yeah!
```

It works because Python strings are iterables. Note that `example('123')` would also return `Yeah!`.